# nethogs not helping understanding suspicious network traffic

Tags: networking

I'm using ubuntu trusty, and my system monitor detects a suspicious network traffic: sistematically I have a 600kB/s download and a 550KB/s upload traffic.

using NetHogs I get:

```
NetHogs version 0.8.0

  PID USER     PROGRAM                            DEV        SENT      RECEIVED       
?     root     192.168.0.3:2049-192.168.0.2:677          406.888  557.587 KB/sec
2861  paolo    /usr/bin/gnome-shell               eth1     0.264    2.196 KB/sec
?     root     unknown TCP                                 0.000    0.000 KB/sec

  TOTAL                                                  407.196  559.816 KB/sec
```

The first line shows my suspicious traffic, but it doesn't give me any info about what process is generating the traffic.

How do I know what proces is responsible for that traffic?

Should I worry about it?

Comment: if your computer is a router or a packet forwarding/nat device than you should expect a lot of interrogation marks in nethogs output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `netstat -tulpn | grep <portnumber>` to find which process is listening on a certain port. Alternatively you can use the `lsof` utility to view open connections, including the process ID.

That said, the connection in Nethogs output seems like an NFS connection (based on the port numbers). Do you have an NFS mount on your system?

Comment: `sudo netstat -tulpn|grep 2049`
doesn't return anything on the system where nethogs detects the "192.168.0.3:2049-192.168.0.2:677" program running, and I haven't any nfs mount...
neither `lsof|grep 2049` detects anything

Comment: `sudo netstat --inet -ap` shows me: `tcp        0      1 192.168.0.2:677         192.168.0.3:2049        SYN_SENT    -` and
I don't know the process; what does the SYN_SENT state mean?

Comment: RESOLVED: it was an impossible nfs mount try.